# Check for dependency in two jobs in Zeke Scehduler for Mainframe

Tags: scheduler, mainframe, zos

This question is specific to Zeke Scheduler for Z/OS.

Is it possible to find if a job is indirectly dependent on another job. 
I can check the direct predecessor and successor of the job. But if I want to find if job A is dependent on job B, I have to check all the successor of job B, and then their depdents as well until I find job A, which is not a very easy method nor reliable.

I checked the manual but could not find any direct option. Please do share if anyone knows any option or a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

We can use command

`PATH LEV  *`

to display all levels of predecessor and successors from `ZEKE` `online` `panel` of browsed event.